Show that a ratio of numbers is always greater than one in ACL2R
There is a straightforward by-hand argument for this question from the Math StackExchange.
I'm trying to produce a mechanically verifiable proof for it using acl2r.
Right now I just want to show a basic fact. For all $n \ge 1$, $\frac{2^{n-1}}{n} \ge 1$.
ACL2 fails to find an induction scheme for 2n/n+1-fact, so I tried to help it out using:
(defthm 2n/n+1-helper-2
   (iff (<= 1 (* (/ (+ 1 (posnfix n))) 2 (posnfix n)))
        (<= (1+ (posnfix n)) (* 2 (posnfix n)))))

To simplify the inequality $1 \le \frac{2n}{n+1}$ to $n + 1 \le 2n$, which is justified because $n + 1$ is positive, but acl2r doesn't accept the validity of that lemma.
So, how do you prove this?
;; -*- mode: acl2; -*-
(in-package "ACL2-LIMIT")

;; Here we are just trying to prove that
;;
;; 2^(n-1) / n >= 1 for all natural numbers n >= 1

(defun posnfix (n)
  (if (= (nfix n) 0) 1 (nfix n)))

(defun power2-value (n)
  (/ (expt 2 (1- (posnfix n))) (posnfix n)))

;; Prove some base cases, may come in handy later.
(defthm power2-value-ge-1-for-1
  (>= (power2-value 1) 1))

(defthm power2-value-ge-1-for-2
  (>= (power2-value 2) 1))

;; Show that 2n/(n+1), the quotient of two successive values of power2 is greater
;; than or equal to 1.
(defun 2n/n+1 (n)
  (/ (* 2 (posnfix n)) (1+ (posnfix n))))

(defthm 2n/n+1-helper
   (>= (* 2 (posnfix n)) (1+ (posnfix n))))

;; (defthm 2n/n+1-helper-2
;;    (iff (<= 1 (* (/ (+ 1 (posnfix n))) 2 (posnfix n)))
;;         (<= (1+ (posnfix n)) (* 2 (posnfix n)))))

;; (defthm 2n/n+1-fact
;;    (>= (2n/n+1 (posnfix n)) 1))

;; (defthm power2-value-ge-1
;;   (>= (power2-value n) 1))
```


The following works:
(include-book "arithmetic-5/top" :dir :system)

(defun power2-value (n)
  (/ (expt 2 (1- (nfix n))) (nfix n)))

(defun mynatp (n)
  (if (not (natp (1- n))) 
      nil
      (if (<= n 1)
          't
          (mynatp (- n 1)))))

(defthm power2-value-ge-1
    (implies (mynatp n)
             (>= (power2-value n) 1))
  :hints (("Goal" :induct (mynatp n)
                  :in-theory 
            (e/d (scatter-exponents-theory
                  prefer-positive-exponents-scatter-exponents-theory)
                 (gather-exponents-theory))
         ))
  )

To do induction you need to define an auxiliary function with the requisite induction scheme. Note that natp doesn't work because it's not defined by recursion, so I define my own.
As for the hints for the arithmetic-5 library, I'll have to be honest I have no idea why this works, I just guessed from looking at this page. I simply know that arithmetic-5 is the most advanced arithmetic library, but sometimes a bit overkill.
